# Web Parts missing in SPFx after gulp clean in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, deployment

I have an SPFx solution with about ten web parts.

This morning I ran a "gulp clean" and for some reason now I can only see two of my tens web parts on my tenant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running below commands in sequence & then upload latest package to app catalog:

- gulp clean
- gulp build
- gulp bundle --ship
- gulp package-solution --ship

After running above commands, you will find package (`.sppkg`) file in `sharepoint\solution` folder inside the project folder.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!